# Extract or filter specifics keys and values of a multidimensional array to another one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to filter or keep selected keys and their values in a multidimensionnal array.
I tried severals methods with array_columns, array_filter, etc ... but I'm not able to keep original structure of my array.

here is original example :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Object
        (
            [not_wanted_key1] => some value
            [wanted_key1] => wanted value
            [wanted_key2] => wanted value
            [not_wanted_key3] => some value
            [wanted_key3] => wanted value



       )

    [1] => Object
        (
            [not_wanted_key1] => some value
            [wanted_key1] => wanted value
            [wanted_key2] => wanted value
            [not_wanted_key3] => some value
            [wanted_key3] => wanted value
        )
)
```

expected result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Object
        (
            [wanted_key1] => wanted value
            [wanted_key2] => wanted value
            [wanted_key3] => wanted value
       )

    [1] => Object
        (
            [wanted_key1] => wanted value
            [wanted_key2] => wanted value
            [wanted_key3] => wanted value
        )
)
```

Someone can guide me ?

Comment: In short you can't because these are objects not sub arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
//test data
$array[] = new stdClass;
$array[0]->not_wanted_key1 = '1';
$array[0]->not_wanted_key2 = '3';
$array[0]->wanted_key1 = '4';
$array[0]->wanted_key2 = '5';
$array[0]->wanted_key3 = '6';

print_r($array);


$map = array_flip(['wanted_key1', 'wanted_key2', 'wanted_key3']);

$res = array_map(function($item) use ($map){
    return array_intersect_key((array) $item, $map);
}, $array);


print_r($res);
```

Output

```
//input array
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [not_wanted_key1] => 1
            [not_wanted_key2] => 3
            [wanted_key1] => 4
            [wanted_key2] => 5
            [wanted_key3] => 6
        )

)
//output array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [wanted_key1] => 4
            [wanted_key2] => 5
            [wanted_key3] => 6
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5efd314b74be509e8cef65409c1d5182cc7f32f)

Pretty simple, the trick is `(array)` casting the object to an array, and then I like to use `array_intersect_key`  but I am to lazy to manually do `$map` so I just flip the values around to be the keys.

This way you can easily add/remove keys you want to keep, just by adding/removing them from `$map`.

If you want to keep the inner array as an object you can cast it back too! so change this:

```
 return array_intersect_key((array) $item, $map);
```

To

```
 return (object)array_intersect_key((array) $item, $map);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [wanted_key1] => 4
            [wanted_key2] => 5
            [wanted_key3] => 6
        )
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31f60014a5d6fa57649af925340525300b345c18)

To be clear all you need is this, the rest is for testing:

```
$map = array_flip(['wanted_key1', 'wanted_key2', 'wanted_key3']);
$res = array_map(function($item)use($map){return array_intersect_key((array)$item,$map);},$array);
```

Comment: sorry for late answer but thanks !
This is exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-filter.php) should do the work.

Simple example:

```php
$original = ['a' => 2, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 6];

$filtered = array_filter($original, function($item) {
    // This anonymous function must return true for keeping your item, or false for not keeping it

    // There I want to keep items with a value more than 4.
    return ($item > 4);
});

// Output of $filtered: ['b' => 5, 'c' => 6]
```

Same example with an array of objects, supposing these have a `value` property:

```php
$filtered = array_filter($original, function($item) {
    // There I want to keep items with a value more than 4.
    return ($item->value > 4);
});

// Output of $filtered: ['b' => 5, 'c' => 6]
```

If your logic is about filtering from keys, the third parameter `flag` must be set to `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY`. Then `$item` will be your keys, not values.

Comment: keys I want to keep are same in all objects but "values" are differents for all those and not necessary numeric.
I want to keep wanted_key1, 2 and 3 **and** their associated different "value"

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ArtisticPheonix's answer, loop through and keep the keys we want by using an intersection:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    ['fruit'=>'apple',  'veg'=>'carrot'],
    ['fruit'=>'banana', 'veg'=>'marrow']
];

$flipped_wanted_keys = array_flip(['fruit']);
foreach($data as &$item)
    $item = array_intersect_key($item, $flipped_wanted_keys);

unset($item);
print_r($data);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruit] => banana
        )

)
```

As you have objects in your array, removing properties requires a different approach, but if you are happy to have a multidimensional array as above as the output, then you just need to cast your object to an array before the key intersection (assuming these are accessible properties).

```
$item = array_intersect_key((array) $item, $flipped_wanted_keys);
```